# Group rows in SQL by ID and Update Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with columns ID,A1, C1,C2...C20, Country, State, Name and 10 other columns similar to country, state, name (A1 is my primary key)

My existing table looks like this

```
ID A1 C1 C2 C3 C4 Country State      Pet Name
1  25 1  1  0   1 USA     Texas      Tucker
1  26 1  0  0   0 USA     California Drum 
2  27 0  1  1   0 Canada  BC         Golden
2  28 0  0  0   1 USA     Ohio       Charlie
3  29 1  1  0   0 Mexico  Tabasco    Chelsea
```

How do I achieve this

```
ID A1 C1 C2 C3 C4 Country State      Pet Name
1  25 1  1  0   1 USA     Texas      Tucker
2  27 0  1  1   1 Canada  BC         Golden
3  29 1  1  0   0 Mexico  Tabasco    Chelsea
```

I want to group by Id and if there was 1 recorded any time I want it to be updated as 1 and I do not want the row which had the repeating information for same ID with a different A1. If there is an ID like 3 which has only one A1, I do not want it to have any changes. Once I get this, Id can become my primary key but I hope I can retain information for other columns such as country, state, name corresponding to A1 recorded first time(as shown in output table).

Please let me know how I can get this done, thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Why do you want to use a `UNION ALL`, `JOIN` *and* `GROUP BY`, or what does it the question to do with them? You only have one table, so what are you looking to `JOIN` and `UNION ALL` to?

Comment: I was not sure if I can use group by or Union-all for this, so I added it as a tag. I am trying a group by ID with a case statement but I am not having much success with it. I am looking to join two rows with the ID and update the columns wherever its one to one and leave remaining columns untouched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select id, min(a1) a1, max(c1) c1, max(c2) c2, max(c3) c3, max(c4) c4
from mytable
group by id
```

If you want to handle more columns, then it is different. I would recommend window `max()`s and `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (select id, a1,
        max(c1) over(partition by id) c1,
        max(c2) over(partition by id) c2,
        max(c3) over(partition by id) c3,
        max(c4) over(partition by id) c4,
        country,
        state,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by a1) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This seems to work, what do I do about other columns? Like I have more than 10 other columns which I want to retain the value corresponding to min(A1)

Comment: @learningtocode2k20: you did not show what the columns look like and how you want them handled, so I can only guess. Maybe add more `max()` for each additional column?

Comment: I have updated my question now, sorry I totally forgot

Comment: @learningtocode2k20: it is not a good practice on SO to substantially modify the question after answers were posted... See my edit.

Comment: I am sorry that I updated the question later, I am going to marks yours as the correct answer and I will try to work with it. Thanks a ton for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the minimum `a1` for each `id`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by a1 asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a1 = (select min(t2.a1) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: Yes this works for other columns but it retains value for C1..C20 which I don't want. I want it to update to 1 which is not happening